# Getting class of parameter of super interface of superclass

Tags: java, generics, reflection, nested-generics

I am having some troubles getting the parameter of an abstract superclass implementing a parametric interface.

I have these classes and interface:

`interface Request<T extends Bean>`

`abstract class ProxyRequest<T extends Bean> implements Request<T>`

`class FooRequest extends ProxyRequest<Foo>`

What I'm trying to achieve is to get `Foo.class` starting from a `FooRequest` instance.

I'm trying this but the result is `T`. What am I doing wrong?

```
FooRequest request = new FooRequest();
Type[] genericInterfaces = request.getClass().getSuperclass().getGenericInterfaces();
Type[] genericTypes = ((ParameterizedType)genericInterfaces[0]).getActualTypeArguments();
System.out.println(genericTypes[0]);
```

Comment: `getSuperClass()` just returns `ProxyRequest::class`.  That knows nothing about the specific generic type arguments.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth indeed, so you're telling me there is no way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking this one step too far. All you need is the generic super class (`ProxyRequest<Foo>`), which you can get by calling [`getGenericSuperclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass()), i.e.:

```
FooRequest request = new FooRequest();
Type[] genericTypes = ((ParameterizedType) request.getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
        .getActualTypeArguments();
System.out.println(genericTypes[0]); // class Foo
```

---

With your snippet you're getting `T` because:

1. `request.getClass()` returns `FooRequest.class`
2. `.getSuperclass()` returns `ProxyRequest.class`
3. `.getGenericInterfaces()` returns an array with `Request<T extends Bean>`
4. `((ParameterizedType)genericInterfaces[0]).getActualTypeArguments()` returns an array with the [`TypeVariable<...>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) `T`, with `Bean` as a bound.

Comment: great, you're right, I was going too far. Now I only need to make this work even in another case, that is when I'm looking for the class of the parameter of an hypothetical `class BarRequest implements Request<Bar>`

Comment: @balsick That should just be a matter of replacing `getGenericSuperclass()` with `getGenericInterfaces()[0]`.

Comment: yes, thanks, just realized that. It would be nice to make it work for any "depth" but I'm not actually in strong need of it at the moment :P